# Is there a way to set the default EOL separator for Out-File in PowerShell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, eol, powershell-5.1

I am looking for a way to set the default EOL marker to `0x0A` when writing text with `Out-File`.

On the internet, I found tons of examples that either replace `0x0D 0x0A` after a file is already written, or `-join` the lines on `0x0A` and then write the concatenated text into the file.

I find both approaches a bit clumsy as I'd just like to write the files with the redirection operator `>`.

So, is there a way to set the EOL style in PowerShell 5.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2, there is *no* way to make PowerShell use a different newline (EOL, line break) format.

It is the *platform-native* newline character or sequence (as reflected in `[Environment]::NewLine`) that is invariably used - both for separating multiple input objects and for the *trailing* newline by default.

To control the newline format, you need to:

- Join the input objects explicitly with the newline character (sequence) of choice, using the `-join` operator, followed by *another* instance if a *trailing* newline is desired ...
- ... *and* use the `-NoNewLine` switch of `Set-Content` / `Out-File` (in lieu of `>`) so as to prevent appending of a *trailing* platform-native newline.

As for potential future enhancements:

- [GitHub feature request #2872](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2872) suggests adding a parameter to `Set-Content`, specifically, to allow specifying the newline format; the request has been green-lighted (a long time ago), but has yet to be implemented - however, I think it isn't comprehensive enough, and it wouldn't help with `Out-File` / `>`; see next point.
- [GitHub feature request #3855](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3855) more generally asked for a `-Delimiter` parameter (to mirror `Get-Content`'s existing parameter by that name) to be added to `Set-Content` / `Add-Content`, `Out-File` and `Out-String`

  - Unfortunately, the proposal was rejected; if it hadn't, you would have been able to configure `>` - a virtual alias of `Out-File` - to use LF-only newlines, for instance, as follows:

    ```sh
    # WISHFUL THINKING 
    $PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Delimiter'] = "`n"
    ```